# Is it necessary to refer to self in: yield(self[i])

Tags: ruby, yield, self

In this example from [a blog post](http://august.lilleaas.net/procs_and_blocks_and_anonymous_functions),

```
class Array
  def each
    i = 0
    while(i < self.length) do
      yield(self[i])
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

my_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
my_array.each {|letter| puts letter }
# => "a"
# => "b"
# => "c"
```

**Is it necessary to use `self` in the statement:**

```
yield(self[i])
```

**Or would it be ok to simply say:**

```
yield i
```

Comment: FYI, "self[i]" is equivalent to "[](i)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are two entirely different things. If you do `yield i` you will actually yield the number i, which will cause the output to be 1 2 3. The point of the code however is to yield the elements of the array, so you yield `self[i]`, which means "the ith element of the array self", or more technically "call the method `[]` on `self` with the argument `i` and yield the result".

Comment: "call the method [] on self with the argument i and return the result" - perfect!

Answer (score 2):

`yield(i)` would yield a block for index, while `yield(self[i])` would yield a block for ith element